Por qué el formulario no cierra?
Tengo una pequeña App en winform
Poseo un formulario principal (No es MDI)
el cual por medio de un temporizador ejecuta una función cada
3 segundo y allí se obtiene un resultado, con dicho resultado
invoco otro formulario donde simplemente se muestran los mismo.
El inconveniente: al momento de cerrar el segundo formulario: NO CIERRA
y al momento de volver a invocar el mismo: simplemente se solapa.
Solo deseo cerrar el mismo o esconderlo hasta volver a invocarlo.
Aquí mi código de inicio(program.cs)
Menu frm = new Menu();
 Menu frm = new Menu();
 frm.Show();
 Application.Run();

Aqui el simple codigo para invocar el segundo
Form1 frm = new Form1(nombreGanador, nombrePremio, fin);
 frm.ShowDialog()

;
En el formulario Form1
Se que la instruccion if (myOff == "S") esta mal, pero es que no encuentro como cerrarlo
private void activarLoop()
{
    stLapso = new Timer(10);
    stLapso.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    stLapso.AutoReset = true;
    stLapso.Enabled = true;
    if (myOff == "S")
    {   stLapso.Enabled = false;
        this.Close();
    }

}


No entiendo donde lo estas cerrando que decis que no cierra...

Podes poner el código del formulario completo?

Veo que el evento Elapsed de tu Timer está suscrito a OnTimedEvent, pero la validación para cerrar el formulario la haces en activarLoop. ¿Quisieras aclararnos mejor porqué haces esto?
